# CAT809 (MAX809) Doesn't give a steady signal when battery voltage recovers

Tags: batteries, esp8266

Actual used part: CAT809RTBI-GT3

I have the CAT809 connected to EN pin of ESP8266. The board is powered by battery.
So when the voltage is going down everything work as expected and the CAT809RTBI-GT3 cut power of microcontroller to protect battery at 2.6v
Now when the voltage goes up gradually again while battery is charging for example 2.7v till 2.9v, the CAT809 gives out erratic voltage jumping around 0.8 till 1.9v and due to that the microcontroller keep goin on off on off...

If I bypass the CAT chip by putting wire from VCC that is at 2.7v to EN pin then the MCU works normally. So it must be the CAT going crazy for some reason.
https://youtu.be/S8oc-zcHzaY

Any ideas what to do? or replacement chip?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This problem is probably due to the change in current load on the battery causing the voltage to change.

When the CAT809 detects the battery voltage has reached the threshold voltage of 2.63V it will enable the processor. The current taken by the processor will load the battery which is only partly charged and cause the battery voltage to drop. It seems that the voltage drops below the 2.6V lower threshold at which point the load will be disconnected and the cycle will repeat with the processor repeatedly turning on and off.

The CAT809 does not have any hysteresis in the threshold voltage so will be sensitive to a few millivolts change in the supply voltage.

About the only cure is to increase the threshold during charging such that that the battery is charged enough that the voltage does not dip excessively when the processor is turned on. You may also be able to improve things by arranging to minimize the load when the power is enabled; for example, are there any other loads beside that processor that don't need to be on when the processor boots. Have the processor turn those on later when the battery is sufficiently charged to support them.

Here is an application note from Texas Instruments describing the issue with their similar part, the TPS3808 and a possible solution by adding hysteresis.

[Adding Hysteresis to Supply Voltage Supervisor](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva360/slva360.pdf?ts=1648187566935)

Comment: My CAT threshold is 2.6v. I understand your analysis, but I have checked using Power Profiler 2 from Nordic Semi. So it is not a battery and the VCC supply is pretty stable and can boot the MCU at 2.7v no problem. The PPK2 can supply up to 1A and I could see the boot up consumption is 175mA.
Any other theory that I could verify? Any other component that could work better? Thank you! I am trying not to freakout :)

Comment: @ramiws - if the voltage into the CAT809 is above threshold but the output is indicating that the voltage is below then something is wrong with that. The ESP8266 enable pin is is described as only being an input pin. So unless you have it miswired it is difficult to see how it could be anything else. The supply voltage must drop a bit when the processor is enabled. Have you measured how much it drops? Is there a voltage drop across a ground wire causing the problem?

Comment: The problem appears even up to 2.9v I thought voltage drop happens when the power source cannot provide the required amps. I have added the wiring schematic to the original post. Can I add capacitor somewhere to help with the voltage drop?

Comment: @ramiws - have you looked at the power rail and the Enable signal with a scope? There may only need to be a short transient of a few microseconds for the CAT809 to register.

Comment: @ramiws - The CAT809 does not have any hysteresis so will be very sensitive to changes  the supply voltage caused by changes in load, just a few millivolts will probably be sufficient. Either using a part with hysteresis or adding hysteresis by changing the CAT809 supply voltage when the enable signal is low can almost certainly  fix the problem.

Comment: So are you saying the voltage drop is so sever that the voltage is going under the threshold? but for very short time . I just looked at the voltage in lab power supply, but that won't show a very short drop. I'll try the scope. Any part with hysteresis that you would recommend?

Comment: I uploaded video of the scope. Power rail does not drop much, and EN pin is in video: https://youtu.be/S8oc-zcHzaY

Comment: @ramiws - I'm afraid that video is not useful - I can't see how much the supply rail drops and what does "not drop much" mean? The CAT809 is sensitive to a few millivolts change. A screen shot is much better, scaled to be able to see the change.

Answer (score 1):

CAT809 is not a part designed to cope with power-on during battery charging. It's a wrong part for the job. It'd need hysteresis for that, and adding hysteresis and external delays would take so many parts that it's not worth doing it. I've tried with as good a model of CAT809 as I could come up with - presuming its internal circuitry, and it was a boondoggle of sorts. Maybe the real part would behave better, but I doubt it, and it wasn't specified for that sort of use anyway.

**It is not in general possible to uses hysteresis-less power monitors that switch loads with power sources with appreciable ESR, e.g. batteries**. They'll always oscillate.

Instead, use a generic, high-performance nanopower comparator with built-in reference. A very good part here would be TLV3012. It consumes about half the power of CAT809, and makes it easy to add hysteresis.

The circuit would be as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2felCXU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Turn-on is around 2.70V, turn-off around 2.61V, and hysteresis is 0.09V. This should work better for you. To increase the hysteresis, decrease R3, and readjust R2 for desired turn-on voltage. You wouldn't want the turn-off voltage to go below 2.62V, though.

The voltage at the positive input of the comparator, at the low and high output states, is, respectively:

$$\begin{aligned}
V_{POS.LO} &= V_{bat} {R_2||R_3 \over R_1 + R_2||R_3} \\
V_{POS.HI} &= V_{bat} {R_2 \over R_1||R_3 + R_2} \\
\end{aligned}$$

Thus, the battery voltage switching points, on rising and falling slope of battery voltage are, respectively:

$$\begin{aligned}
V_{SW.RISE} &= V_{REF} {R_1 + R_2||R_3 \over R_2||R_3} 
         = V_{REF} \left({R_1 \over R_2||R_3} + 1 \right) \\
        &= V_{REF} \left[ R_1 \left( {1\over R_2} + {1\over R_3} \right) + 1 \right] \\
        &= V_{REF} \left( {R_1(R_2 + R_3) \over R_2R_3} + 1 \right) \\ 
V_{SW.FALL} &= V_{REF} {R_1||R_3 + R_2 \over R_2} 
         = V_{REF} \left({R_1||R_3 \over R_2} + 1 \right)\\
        &= V_{REF} \left[{ 1 \over R_2 \left( {1\over R_1} + {1\over R_3}\right)}  + 1 \right] \\
        &= V_{REF} \left( {R_1R_3 \over R_2(R_1+R_3)} + 1 \right)\\
\end{aligned}$$

Here, the switching points are:

$$\begin{aligned}
V_{SW.RISE} &= 1.242{\rm V} \left({1{\rm M} \over 0.88{\rm M}||30{\rm M}} + 1 \right) 
         = 2.695{\rm V} \\
V_{SW.FALL} &= 1.242{\rm V} \left({1{\rm M}||30{\rm M} \over 0.88{\rm M}} + 1 \right)
         = 2.608{\rm V} \\
\end{aligned}$$

The hysteresis and mid-switching voltages are then as follows:

$$\begin{aligned}
V_{HYST} &= V_{SW.RISE} - V_{SW.FALL} \\
   &= V_{REF}{R_1 \over R_2} \left( {R_2+R_3 \over R_3} - {R_3 \over R_1+R_3} \right) \\
V_{MID} &= {V_{SW.RISE} + V_{SW.FALL} \over 2} \\
   &= V_{REF} \left[ {R_1 \over 2R_2} \left(  {R_2 + R_3 \over R_3} + {R_3 \over R_1+R_3} \right) + 1 \right] \\
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Thanks for comprehensive answer.
I tried my luck with TPS3809L30DBVR. It has 35mv threshold hysteresis. But with no big difference from the CAT809. The TLV3012 is way too expensive, it is more expensive than the MCU itself.

Comment: But what I still do not understand, is what this is still happening even with 0.3v higher than the threshold at 2.9v? and using 3A lab power supply. The rail voltage is not dropping under the threshold voltage of 2.6v